# I felt mistreated during the interview. How should I proceed?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, salary, new-job

In this round, we discussed the technical solutions I provided. I am confident in my expertise in this area.

While the interviewer pointed out some minor errors, which I anticipated due to the time constraints, but completely agreed that it can be better, he continued only negatively speaking and he did not allow me to speak throughout the one-hour interview. He focused solely on the negative aspects of my code. It felt like a monologue where he only highlighted the flaws. He got so much into it and got excited how he found mistakes there. By the end, he stated that I wasn't a strong candidate and that their decision would be “very, very“ challenging. He mentioned that they'd let me know next week, but hinted that the outcome might be more negative than positive.

I was not given an opportunity to explain my code, discuss the rationale behind my decisions, or mention that I am in talks with other companies and cannot wait for a week for their response. He just didn’t want to hear, interrupting me on the first word.

His behaviour was like I was desperate and that they were my only option for employment. I suspect his attitude was probably a bit influenced by our previous interview, where he mentioned I was asking for too high of a salary. However, my salary expectations are in line with the current market rates and even on a lower range.

He was overly rude, overly excited in a bad way, looking down on me. I stayed polite and thanked him in the end for the feedback and we finished the meeting. I cried for two hours afterwards. I was mistreated few times as a woman and foreigner in this country and I cannot handle it anymore.

Even though I wanted to join this company earlier, I am thinking to send them a polite email about to thank them and decline the further application process.

What’s your suggestion on this and how can I stop the application process? Or should I wait a week for them which I wouldn’t like to do to be honest. I would honestly rather be without work than to work with this guy, if by a miracle he accepts my application.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149356/discussion-on-question-by-nobly-noob-i-felt-mistreated-during-the-interview-how); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: "cannot wait for a week for their response" what makes you think you have to? Have you promised them to wait for their answer before proceeding with other options?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Call up/email the Hiring Manager/HR rep/Agent:

"Hi, I want to let you know that I am no longer interested in pursuing this opportunity. I don't believe this company is the right fit for me and don't want to waste your time, so I am letting you know that I am withdrawing my application. I wish you all the best in finding the right candidate for you"

Comment: I'd do this too, but I'd wait for a response first, just to make the interviewer waste his time writing it, then I'd drag my heels a bit before writing back and asking for detailed feedback (then I might email every two days asking for an update on that feedback), and then _finally_ I'd tell them that I've taken another job and am not interested. Oh and the last thing I'd do is go to glassdoor.com and give feedback on the awful interview. 'Hell hath no fury like a jobseeker scorned' ;-) (actually in reality I'd stop writing to them as soon as I got a new job)

Answer (score 83):

That person behaved like a jerk. We cannot possibly tell if that is what they *are*, or just a role they played to gain a tactical advantage to destroy your self esteem and make you accept a very lowball offer. In other words, whether the company accidentially sent a jerk, or intentionally sent a jerk. Either way, that's not a good company.

Anyway, declining is the right choice. Being professional is something I would advise, but I would also suggest to commmunicate your decision and it's reasons clearly.

> What’s you suggestion on this and how I can stop the application process?

Write them a clear and concise email:

> Dear $HRPERSON,
>
> Yesterday's interview with Mr. $INTERVIEWER has shown me that your company will likely not be able to provide the mutual respect and cooperation I am looking for. I withdraw my application for $JOB.
>
> Best Regards,
>
> $ME

Done. Professional behaviour does not mean you have to lie and sugarcoat everything to everyone. You can be direct and still professional. After all, there is nothing you want from them. They have been jerks. The most professional things to do is to say "ah, no thank you."

Comment: For completeness - this _may_ be the right approach, but it comes with cost. It is unfair that the victims of such unfair treatment bear this cost, but don't blame me. You may come across this bully interviewer again, or they may somehow be opining on your CV - in which case, if your legitimate complaint gets them in trouble, they may hold a grudge. You need to weight this against the potential benefit of recovering your interview process and the (unlikely) justice against the bully.

Comment: @nvoigt, your answers are the best. I also think like you do. I dint want them to be I told you she is a weak candidate but on other hand,  I don’t want to wait a week to hear again how bad candidate I am. This guy was egocentric and I am afraid very honest, he’s German, but this power game was afwul. He’s an old guy, probably lonely guy. Anyway  that company’s culture seems toxic if they do this things on the job interviews.

Comment: @Bennet: If this were my company, I'd be more than interested to hear that a interviewer of mine is leaving potential candidates with a bad impression of my company. So... it can go both ways.

Comment: IMO this phrasing is better than the current accepted answer, Take pride in your work, be ethical and honest has always been my motto, and it always played great at the end. If you have other opportunities, don't hesitate to tell what you think, instead of using pre-formatted expressions with the goal of getting a certain reaction, that often lead to incomprehension. Who knows, maybe this recruiter is not liked in the company and you'll get good points higher for standing up. Don't take it as a vengeance, just say what you think in a simple and polite manner

Comment: That's just sounding like the typical "sour grapes" from a rejected candidate. They are not going to believe it.

Comment: @Hilmar If one person responds that way, maybe – but if they followed up on the complaint, they could easily distinguish. If _multiple_ people respond this way, or there are a suspicious number of rejections in addition to one complaint, that suggests something's up.

Comment: @Hilmar Would you feel differently if this came as a response to an offer of employment, rather than after a second stage interview? It certainly eliminates the "sour grapes" angle.

Comment: @Heinzi If this were my company I'd be inclined to believe my interviewer when he tells a story that conflicts with the OP's.

Comment: @user142083: Depends on the interviewer. Some people just have difficult personalities. I can totally imagine a situation where both (a) the candidate gets a bad impression of the company and (b) the interviewer honestly considers himself to be completely innocent. And if this happens more than once, people might start to question whether the interviewer is really the right person for that job.

Comment: Being a jerk for tactical reasons sounds like the behaviour of a jerk to me.

Comment: It's true that this approach may not result in any consequences for this interviewer. But the approach in the accepted answer definitely won't.

Comment: Or they sent a person who doesn't want to interview, has no idea how to interview, and behaved as a jerk because they panicked or assumed (without any training or thought) that's how you're *supposed to* interview. Again, that would tell more about the company than whether that particular person is a jerk in everyday life.

Comment: @Hilmar `That's just sounding like the typical "sour grapes" from a rejected candidate` but in this case the candidate has not been rejected yet. They potentially still have something to lose, which IMHO lends more credibility to their complaint

Comment: As the only answer so far that opts to provide feedback, I feel that it doesn't go far enough. If you're going to provide feedback, I'd argue that it needs to be detailed and specific. At present, this is vague, bordering on passive-aggressive, and so achieves none of its aims (IMHO).

Comment: The sentence you have chosen is a little bit passive aggressive. I think it might be received better if you flatly state something like "while the feedback during the interview was valuable, the interviewer was very unprofessional, and as a result I believe that the company's broader culture will not be a good fit". This way, it doesn't carry emotional undertones and is more likely to be understood at face value - namely, their interviewer blew it and not "wow, that interviewee was really buthurt huh?"

Answer (score 44):

### Just walk away and forget about it

You met a bad interviewer, they flunked their side of the interview as a result, and you now know you want nothing to do with them. The interview served its purpose for you, although probably not for them. Why waste another moment or thought on it? You don't need to "withdraw your application" or anything, you just don't contact them again, and in the event they offer you the job you either decline or try your arm on asking for way more money (after all, do you care if you don't get the job?).

#### Next time just politely leave the interview

There's no point wasting either of your time once you've determined you don't want to work for the company, just stand up say "okay, I think we're done here", politely thank them for their time, shake their hand and walk out.

Comment: I once had this kind of interviewer too, I was interviewed by 2 person that day, the first lady was a delight to talk with, sounds reasonable and nice to talk to. the second one was the nightmare, since he's the technical person I figured I might work closer to him than the first lady, he berates my decision to job hop to no end, even after I explained the reasoning behind it and after 15+ min of him complaining he can't even do a competent job of informing me about what next. I rejected the next interview call. If only I didn't met the 2nd person, I might accept if I was offered a position.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. The only person you owe anything to is yourself.

Comment: **OP:** The interviewer inadvertently did you a favor by showing you their true colors. You lost the time spent in the interview, but gained some perspective. This company is an example of where you *don't* want to work. As for whether this "jerk" is an accurate representative of the company culture as a whole - you at least know that the company culture isn't positively oriented enough or influential enough to prevent this kind of employee from behaving with a bullying attitude. That's all you need to know. **+1** for "Just walk away".

Comment: @Mentalist the OP's interview experience was indeed a red flag. However, there are still scenarios in which such an interview is just an unhappy accident, such as the original interviewer getting sick and the actual interviewer being unprepared or simply unsuitable. Chances of thinigs working out despite the bad interview are low but not zero, so it's more a question of where to invest one's time.

Comment: Don’t walk out of interviews, (especially if it’s over video conferencing) unless you’re 100% certain you never ever want to work at that company because there’s a very good chance HR will put you on a “do not hire” list. Of course if your safety is in danger or they’re engaging in sexual harassment that’s different. But if they’re just being obnoxious, while it might feel good to walk out, it’s a really bad idea. Why burn that bridge?

Comment: 100% Correct.
You only had a peek of what would await you if you joined them. Would you want to scar your well-being daily with this workplace's individual?
Immediately leave the interview when you see such toxic, scolding, and dominant-driven behaviors, they reflect a lot on the company. Just make sure to be transparent on what happened with their HR.

Answer (score 41):

Some people are just jerks and bullies.  If the person is just clueless or is acting like that because he only wants people who'll accept his verbal abuse doesn't matter.  Interviews go both directions and - however attractive this company may have appeared before the call - this company has just flunked your interview of them.  Walk away and continue looking elsewhere.

Comment: Most important is that an interview goes both ways. I cannot judge how good OP was technically, but the interviewer’s behaviour was unacceptable. The company failed their interview.

Comment: They sure did. The question is now, should I send them the email that I have decided to go in another direction?

Comment: @Noblynoob you don't have to send an email. They said they would contact you within a week. Just let them do that. Pursue other options in the meantime. If they send you their decision: if it's a rejection, simply move on with your life, no further contact needed. If it's indeed an offer, simply write them a mail in the style of DemonLords answer.
Don't overthink this ;) there a lots of interviews taking place all the time, you really don't owe this company that much time / bearing.

Comment: @Noblynoob What if they come back to you in a week, meeting your requested salary, and you don't have other options? Best not to burn bridges.

Comment: I have other options but even if I don’t, I’d never work there

Comment: @Noblynoob Then just look for other positions and decline their offer if they make one - no need to waste your life on writing back to them. You're making this into a bigger deal than it needs to be.

Comment: @Noblynoob, statistically, most recruiters who say they will call back do not call you back. If they call or email you, then you can simply say "I am no longer interested in this role, maybe another role at another time. Have a great day!" If you get buddy-buddy with the recruiter (if there is a separate recruiter), or they want honest feedback, then offer a phone call - but prepare what you want to say in advance, and stick to that. Do not offer any further comment about the interview. Look at Fortune 500 companies, governments, and Universities. Large organizations will treat you properly.

Comment: @Noblynoob I strongly agree with GenericUserName. Let them waste their time with the  very very challenging decision, as they put it. If they give you a job offer then tell them after the pointless berating you received at your last interview you didn't accept to hear back from them and, as a result, you've already engaged other opportunities. Your feedback about being mistreated will have the biggest impact if it's in the context of refusing a job offer. If you don't get an offer then they'd likely disregard your feedback as just someone who is disgruntled at not getting an offer.

Answer (score 26):

In short, keep up the job search and when they eventually write back to you, you can do the polite thing and respond that you're thankful for their time but you're currently pursuing other offers.

As a woman dev, I don't know if this is because we're women, but I've definitely experienced this too. And I've spoken to male devs and I feel like they tend to not take similar situations personally (some don't take personally even things they should at least consider...). Personally, I don't think one or the other is "the correct way" to be, we just need to know where we're at and it's our job to align accordingly - try to be more receptive or more ignorant of other's opinions, whichever's the case.

What helps me in times like these is focusing on facts - what I've already accomplished. If you can afford money-wise to stick it out, just look for more opportunities. I promise you that kind of treatment is not normal. They're just fishing for people who don't have the boundaries to understand this is not OK treatment so they can abuse them for years - in lowball salaries, neverending overtimes etc. Your reaction and repulsion is a good thing - it's telling you to stay away if possible. Not all people have developed that ability.

If you want to put this frustration you're feeling somewhere - take some courses to improve your skill. Not because some weirdo said weird stuff but because you want to be the best you can be and programming is a pretty awesome skill where no one person will ever know everything.

Also, don't wait for companies to respond before starting to reach out to others, even if the process is going well. I know it's hard to when they assign homework but you don't have to accept their deadlines and set a different weekend for doing the work than offered. You lose out more by not applying to multiples than by stating you have other options. Plus it's easier to walk out mid bs like that interview you described when you have other things to do.

Comment: Thank you @vspmis, this meant a lot, and I am truly grateful for this advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "walk out mid bs"?

Comment: @pandabear thank you, and best of luck in your job search!

Comment: @PeterMortensen , thank you for asking, I see how it could be understood many ways. I meant that if I'm in a job interview and I see this will not be a match, as an interviewee I find it appropriate to say thank you, state it's not a match and politely end the interview early. And it's easier to do that when you're perusing other options. Personally, I find the described treatment of a possible employee some serious bs. If I truly thought someone's actually so subpar for a role, I would not ask them to come back and then fry them in person, therefore this treatment smells like bs to me.

Comment: I think it's more to do with my neurodiversity than masculinity but I just don't take things personally. For what it's worth, though, this interviewer as described does present multiple red flags and I wouldn't want to work for them on that basis alone. An interview is an opportunity for the candidate to show their skill, not for the interviewer to enjoy a power trip.

Comment: @TimB Yeah, either direction can be a blessing in one case and a curse in another. I bet OPs very perceptive of others opinions and takes them into account, making it a breeze to work with them, but right now that openness is letting the bs get to them. I hope now that they see everyone agreeing it was not ok they get to breathe in and focus on their future job prospects without a worry about the mess of a dev they had the displeasure to encounter. Guys like that give the rest of us a bad name, he's like the arrogant loser cliché that plagues programming.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think she means: stand up, walk to the door, open it, and leave. I have done that a few times: in one case I was told to rewrite my CV to remove all results (e.g. my work led to a measurable improvement of the organization's bottom line). I thanked the HR droid for clarifying that their clients did not want results, since I don't work for that sort of organization.

Comment: @SimonCrase, with all due respect, but did you just explain what I meant right after I left a comment explaining what I meant?

 Other than that, I think it's great you know what you want, but similarly, the HR person knows what are the company's requirements. Unless I misunderstood and they were rude about it, calling this person an "HR droid" for stating their requirements is uncalled for.

Comment: @vspmis With the utmost respect, you were not present during the interview, unless you were the HR girl (which would help to explain why you are so quick to leap to here defence).

Comment: @SimonCrase, as I wrote, I don't know if they were rude about it. And unless you were interviewed by an underage child, you were interviewed by a woman, not a girl.

Comment: @vspmis As I said, you weren't there. If you're relying on your mind reading ability to work out what "really" happened, it has let you down badly.

Comment: @SimonCrase, correct, there is no way I can know if you were interviewed by an underage child, dear boy of measurable improvements.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, concentrate on your other opportunities and leave this prospect in a rear view mirror.

Why would you want to proactively contact a company to withdraw your candidacy?

From your post it is still debatable if you will be chosen for next step.

Unless it is negative aftertaste from the meeting you want to mend, by actively stating that you will no longer be their candidate

Answer (score 1):

My advice is approximately the opposite of most of the other answers.
This is crucial.
A correct decision may improve your life.
A less good one may make litte difference but lead to a missed opportunity.

#### Have confidence in yourself and your abilities.

##### Do not let a moron interviewer get you down or weaken your defences.

Instead - to quote several time honoured axioms that are based on long experience:

- Do not "burn your boats".
- Do not cross your bridges before you come to them.
- Do not cut off your nose to spite your face.

You have nothing to lose by waiting to see what happemns.
By walking away before you see what happens you may feel that you have "saved face" BUT this is letting your pride take precedence over your best interests.

I'm "oldish".
I have been in situations where I 'walked away' to save face, and regretted it greatly afterwards.
I have also been in many situations where "I just got on with it", and in many cases things worked out better than I could reasonably have hoped, and in cases where this didn't happen it cost me nothing except maybe hurt pride to have waited to see what happens.

Over 20 years ago I was in a situation where essentially everyone in two groups thought badly of me. (I had acted to postpone the merging of two groups because I considered that the interests and rights of those with little authority or stature had not been properly addressed.)
And everyone in one of the groups essentially hated me - due to having been told lies about me by someone in a leadership position who I subsequently found out had mental health issues. (one group was almost solely Polynesian - they were told that I was racist and a troublemaker).

It was openly suggested that I did not belong and that I should leave.

I received [valued advice](https://biblehub.com/ecclesiastes/10-4.htm) to the effect that I should not abandon my position, but should continue to fill the role that was expected of me, and that doing so in a polite and non-confrontational manner could lead to superb outcomes. To my utter amazement (and that of many looking on to see what would happen), after an extrmely uncomfortable period it worked out beyond brilliantly for me.  Utterly unbelievably well.

I suggest that it may for you also, and can do no obvious harm.

- It MAY be that the company offers you a position.
- It may be that the interviewer and interview were not a good indication of what the company is like.
- If they do make an offer, and the remuneration offered is anything other than brilliant, you can turn them down.
  Or counteroffer at what you consider to be a superb rate.
  They may accept!
- And if you decide that you may accept, THEN you can ask about the interview and ask why it was as it was.
- In all cases you can be in control.
- The only thing that may be hurt is your pride, and that only if you allow it to be.

And, if they do not make an offer you have still lost nothing.

So - "chin up", go for it! and God bless.

---

Note: While this answer is derived from my prior answer it is NOT a duplicate and I wish to offer both answers. It does not seem to be against site rules to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Something I've done before (and with some fairly major companies) is email the CEO and HR team explaining my experience - informing them of who interviewed me and why I believed their behaviour was not appropriate.

The moment I sent said email, I accepted that the company almost certainly wasn't for me, but by giving the CEO all the information about how their company is run, it gives them a chance to improve it.

In my particular case, I was asked to re-interview with another person, with my expenses paid for.  While I declined, it did result in what some would consider a positive outcome.

Answer (score -2):

My advice is approximately the opposite of most of the other answers.

#### Have confidence in yourself and your abilities.

##### Do not let a moron interviewer get you down or weaken your defences.

BUT  - to quote several time honoured axioms that are based on long experience:

- Do not "burn your boats".
- Do not cross your bridges before you come to them.
- Do not cut off your nose to spite your face.

You have nothing to lose by waiting to see what happemns.
By walking away before you see what happens you may feel that you have "saved face" BUT this is letting your pride take precedence over your best interests.

I'm "oldish".
I have been in situations where I 'walked away' to save face, and regretted it greatly afterwards.
I have also been in many situations where "I just got on with it", and in many cases things worked out better than I could reasonably have hoped, and in cases where this didn't happen it cost me nothing except maybe hurt pride to have waited to see what happens.

Over 20 years ago I was in a situation where essentially everyone in two groups thought badly of me. (I had acted to postpone the merging of two groups because I considered that the interests and rights of those with little authority or stature had not been properly addressed.)
And everyone in one of the groups essentially hated me - due to having been told lies about me by someone in a leadership position who I subsequently found out had mental health issues. (one group was almost solely Polynesian - they were told that I was racist and a troublemaker). It was openly suggested that I did not belong and that I should leave.  In that case I turned to God for guidance. It's up to you whether you do the same, but in my case the result was stunning. I received advice in the form of a single bible verse. I'm not going to go into any detail how this happened - but it was essentially a random process from a human involvement point of view. I had never seen the verse before and could have searched for it for days without finding it.
It is [Ecclesiastes 10:4](https://biblehub.com/ecclesiastes/10-4.htm) .
Here is one version - many variants at the above link

- If your boss is angry at you, don’t quit! A quiet spirit can overcome even great mistakes.

It worked out beyond brillianlty for me.  Utterly unbelievably well.
I suggest that it may for you also, and can do no obvious harm.

---

It MAY be that the company offers you a position.
It may be that the interviewer and interview were not a good indication of what the company is like.
If they do make an offer, and the remuneration offered is anything other than brilliant, you can turn them down. Or counteroffer at what you consider to be a superb rate.  They may accept!
And if you decide that you may accept, THEN you can ask about the interview and ask why it was as it was.
In all cases you can be in control.
If they do not make an offer you have still lost nothing.

So - "chin up", go for it! and God bless.

Comment: I don't think mentioning God or the bible is nessesary here.

Comment: @guest  Necessary is such a strong word :-).  I have a nmber of up votes (according to notifications) but -2 overall. I assume, perhaps incorrectly, that's more to do with  people's religious predilections than the quality of my advice overall. FWIW, I'm reasonablty confident after a long (73 years) & eventful lifetime (so far :-) ) that my advice is better than the "walk away" ones.  ie apart from hurt pride she has nothing to lose by waiting to see.  Menitoning God is fundamental to my experience - should that be missed out because it's not so for others? (Apparentl;y "yes" in your opinion)